# javax.mail.MessagingException:

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

```
package com.mca2b;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  
import javax.activation.*;  


public class SampleMail 
{
     public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{  
          String to = "kalgaonkarsiddhesh@gmail.com";//change accordingly  
          String from = "siddhesh.kalgaonkar@ves.ac.in";//change accordingly  
          String host = "localhost";//or IP address  
          // Get system properties
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();

          // Setup mail server
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

          // Get the default Session object.
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

          try{
             // Create a default MimeMessage object.
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

             // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

             // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));

             // Set Subject: header field
             message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

             // Now set the actual message
             message.setText("This is actual message");

             // Send message
             Transport.send(message);
             System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
          }catch (SendFailedException mex) {
             mex.printStackTrace();
          }

     }  

}
```

I am getting Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException.  Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25 nested exception is:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.  So whats the solution for it ?

I am posting here the correct code for sending mail via gmail in struts 2.  For different providers you will have to change SMTP host accordingly :)

```
package org.entity;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class DonorForgotAction extends ActionSupport
{
DonorForgot forg;
    public DonorForgotAction() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
    public DonorForgot getForg() {
        return forg;
    }
    public void setForg(DonorForgot forg) {
        this.forg = forg;
    }
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        String email,pass;
        final String username = "";
        final String password = "";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foryou", "root", "siddheshkk");
            System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
            PreparedStatement ps = con
                    .prepareStatement("select email,password from donorinfo where contact=?");
            ps.setString(1, forg.getContact());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                email=rs.getString("email");
                pass=rs.getString("password");
                System.out.println("Here is your email id "+email+"and password is "+pass);
                try {
                    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(email));
                    message.setSubject("Password Retrieval");
                    message.setText("Dear user your password is "+ pass);
                    Transport.send(message);
                    System.out.println("Done");

                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "success";
            } else {
                return "error";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "success";
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no SMTP server listening on port 25 on localhost. Specify the correct hostname and port number of the SMTP server you want to connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forget two steps:

- Your password
- The Authenticator

Also, maybe you didn't have any local mail server who listen the port 25 on your localhost (javax.mail.MessagingException).

Here I use the port 587.

So try this code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.SendFailedException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class SampleMail 
{
     public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
     {  
          final String from = "siddhesh.kalgaonkar@ves.ac.in"; // change accordingly
          final String password = "yourPassword"; // change accordingly
          String to = "kalgaonkarsiddhesh@gmail.com"; // change accordingly
          String host = "localhost"; // or IP address

          // Get system properties
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();

          // Setup mail server
          properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
          properties.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
          properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          properties.put("mail.user", from);
          properties.put("mail.password", password);

          // Get the default Session object.
          Authenticator auth = new Authenticator()
          {
              public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
              {
                  return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
              }
          };
          Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

          try
          {
             // Create a default MimeMessage object.
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

             // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

             // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));

             // Set Subject: header field
             message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

             // Now set the actual message
             message.setText("This is actual message");

             // Send message
             Transport.send(message);
             System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
          }
          catch (SendFailedException mex)
          {
             mex.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
}
```

I use this code, if that can help you:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


class SampleMail
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        new Email("yourEmail(sendTheMessage)", "yourEmailPassword", "yourEmail(recvTheMessage)", "subject", "message"); // Send a message

        String[] attachments = {"/home/user/Documents/text.odt"};
        new Email("yourEmail(sendTheMessage)", "yourEmailPassword", "yourEmail(recvTheMessage)", "subject", "message", attachments); // send a message with attachments
    }
}

class Email
{
    private String host, port = "587";

    Email(String mailFrom, String password, String mailTo, String subject, String message) throws Exception
    {
        if (mailFrom.contains("@gmail"))
            this.host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        else if (mailFrom.contains("@yahoo"))
            this.host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        else
            this.host = "smtp.live.com";

        sendEmail(host, port, mailFrom, password, mailTo, subject, message, null);
    }

    Email(String mailFrom, String password, String mailTo, String subject, String message, String[] attachFiles) throws Exception
    {
        if (mailFrom.contains("@gmail"))
            this.host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        else if (mailFrom.contains("@yahoo"))
            this.host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        else
            this.host = "smtp.live.com";

        sendEmail(host, port, mailFrom, password, mailTo, subject, message, attachFiles);
    }

    private void sendEmail(String host, String port, final String userName, final String password, String toAddress, String subject, String message, String[] attachFiles) throws Exception
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.user", userName);
        properties.put("mail.password", password);

        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator()
        {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = {new InternetAddress(toAddress)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0)
        {
            for (String filePath : attachFiles)
            {
                MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                try
                {
                    attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
                }
                finally
                {
                    multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
                }
            }
        }
        msg.setContent(multipart);

        Transport.send(msg);
    }
}
```

But here, you have to change the host for allow something else than a gmail, yahoo or hotmail account.

Comment: Thanks alot for the above code :) but still its giving authentication failed exception even after entering correct id and password ? why is it so ?

Comment: I am using second code that has attachment section

Comment: You have to allow the external applications to send an email. Check your Email box. You have to check a box in your parameters.

Comment: Here i am posting simple java mail program which works perfectly just need to add jar files i.e mail,activation,and additional jar :)

Comment: Where have you download javax.mail?

Comment: means you want to the link for downloading or you are asking where i have saved that jar file ?

Comment: 1) Download java mail from here: [JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home). 2) Include JavaMail.jar 3) Use one of the source code above. 4) Complete the code with your email and your password. 5) Allow your mailbox to be use by an external application. If you don't know how to do it, you should automatically receive an email for allow it after the first run of your software. If that doesn't work, try with two email from google/hotmail (because of the host).